# Assign the SKAction returned when running play() on an SKAudioNode?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaudionode

The docs seem to suggest that running play on an SKAudioNode returns an SKAction

> play() Creates an action that tells an audio node to start playback.

```
class func play() -> SKAction
```

So my wee logic tells me I can get at this returned Action, and assign it to a variable or constant like this:

```
var mySoundAction = mySoundNode.run(SKAction.play())
```

But Xcode tells me I'm an idiot and have no idea what I'm doing when I try to do this:

```
self.run(mySoundAction)
```

It tells me it's unable to convert a type of void to that of an SKAction.

What am I doing wrong? How deluded am I in my goals to have an action name for something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SKAction.play()
```

returns an `SKAction`, and

```
mySoundNode.run(SKAction.play())
```

runs that action on `mySoundNode`. The `run()` method returns `Void` ("nothing"), so with

```
var mySoundAction = mySoundNode.run(SKAction.play())
```

you run the "play" action on the node and assign `()` to `var mySoundAction`. What you perhaps meant is

```
var mySoundAction = SKAction.play()
// ... 
self.run(mySoundAction)
```

Comment: so... on a scale of 1 to 10, I'm about 8 points worth of deluded? 8.5?

Comment: oh wise one, do you happen to know anything about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40429475/copied-skaudionode-unresponsive-why, I am clueless, befuddled and confused.